# Grails batch read optimization

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I need to re-index all of my domain instances from a live legacy database on a regular basis using a custom [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org) implementation.

All of the suggestions I have found so far have all been for optimizing batch **write** operations.

Many of the tables have hundreds of thousands if not millions of records and the simple solution of `domain.list().each { ... }` appears to load the entire dataset into memory at once.

Using Hibernate [ScrollableResults](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html) seems like a good solution but it works at the [RecordSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) level and doesn't recreate the actual domain objects.  I could use the `id` field to [`read()`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/read.html) the instance but that seems inefficient.

The [Searchable](http://grails.org/plugin/searchable) plugin seems to perform an efficient `reindex` operation.

What other options or optimizations are there for batch reading domain instances successfully?

---

**UPDATE**

I recently stumbled across a 4 year old thread on the Grails mailing list with an [answer](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Most-efficient-GORM-method-of-iterating-lots-of-records-tp1353186p1353188.html) from [@BurtBeckwith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160313/burt-beckwith) that suggests using a ScrollableResultSet would be inefficient.  He recommends paging through the records using standard GORM methods and clearing the session in batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Using a tradition Java for loop will save you a little bit of overhead.

2) Chunking the data might help.  You can use max: and offset: to get chunks of 100 or 1000 that way you're always dealing with a smaller set: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html
There might be issues with this though if you're modifying the objects in that table or if new data gets added in the middle of a workflow. (I'll leave that for you to test :)

3) Using SQL or HSQL to get a hold of all of the ids then using Grails .load() might help as well.  http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/load.html

4) I've tried to implement some large batch jobs using Grails/Hibernate before and found that it just really didn't work well.  I'd advise you to work directly with the database using SQL if at all possible.  It will by far be the quickest.

Comment: I think you have the right idea with a ScrollableResults query of all the instance id's and then loading them individually.  The only issue is legacy tables with composite primary keys.

Comment: Depending on your DB implementation, using an offset can add huge amounts of overhead as you are repeatedly selecting the same data.  This is probably not an issue for simple queries, but can add lots of time for more complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a utility class similar to below to manual load records in batches

```
 class Paginator {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("grails.app.Paginator")

    int batchSize
    int totalCount

    public void eachPage(Closure c) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = Holders.applicationContext.sessionFactory

        if(totalCount > 0) {
            (0..totalCount -1).step(batchSize) { int offset ->
                log.debug "Executing batch $offset to ${offset + batchSize}"
                try {
                    c.call(batchSize, offset)
                    sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    log.error "Error encountered while executing batch [$offset - ${batchSize + offset}]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
Paginator p = new Paginator(batchSize:500, totalCount: Domain.count())
p.eachPage {def max, def offset ->
    List rows = Domain.list(max:max, offset:offset)
    //do some thing with records
}
```

You can use the paginator with  gorm or direct sql or anything.